# How should I use React to display global error messages?

Tags: reactjs

I have an `App` component at the top level, and then within that component, I have one called `ErrorMessages`.

I put my `App` component's state into a context, and then elsewhere in my app, if an error occurs, I set errors on the `App` component's context.

The `App` component will then pass the errors to `ErrorMessages` via prop, and then the error messages will display.

The problem is, I can't seem to clear out the error messages.

What I've tried so far is, using the cleanup mechanism of `useEffect` to clear the errorMessages.

Say I have a component called `UserRegistration`, the user doesn't enter an e-mail address, and I set an error "email address required", this displays just fine.

Now, when `UserRegistration` is unmounted, I want to clear the error messages out of the `App` context.

How might I achieve this?

This is my app component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    // For errors in the format of:
    // [{message: "first_name missing..."}, {message: "Email address in use..."}]
    setErrorMessages = (errors) => { 
        this.setState({errors}) }
    // Other messages not in the format above. Can set "alert-warning" or
    // "alert-success" type messages.
    setStatusMessage = (statusType, statusMessage) => {
        this.setState({statusType, statusMessage}) }

    clearAllMessages = () => {
        this.setState({errors: [], statusType: null, statusMessage: null}) }


    setAuthToken = () => {}
    setLoaded = (val) => { this.setState({loaded: val}) }


    state = {
        user: {},

        loaded: false,
        errors: [],
        statusType: null,
        statusMessage: null,

        setErrorMessages: this.setErrorMessages,
        clearAllMessages: this.clearAllMessages,
        setStatusMessage: this.setStatusMessage,

        setLoading: this.setLoading,
        setLoaded: this.setLoaded,
        setAuthToken: this.setAuthToken,
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App container">
                <React.StrictMode>
                    <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                        <BrowserRouter>
                            {this.state.statusMessage ? 
                                <div className={"alert alert-" + this.state.statusType}>{this.state.statusMessage}</div> : null}
                            <ErrorMessages list={this.state.errors} />
                            {!this.state.loaded ? <LoaderWidget /> : null }
                            <IssueBrowser />
                        </BrowserRouter>
                    </AppContext.Provider>
                </React.StrictMode>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If I use the cleanup mechanism of `useEffect` in a lower level component, I get the "maximum depth exceeded" error, and the page hangs.

Here's the component I'm calling `useEffect` in:

```
const UserRegistration = (props) => {
    const appContext = useContext(AppContext)
    const history = useHistory();

    const registerUser = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        appContext.setLoaded(false)

        let payload = {
            first_name: event.target.first_name.value,
            last_name: event.target.last_name.value,
            email_address: event.target.email_address.value,
            password: event.target.password.value }

        Users.create(payload)
            .then(response => { 
                appContext.setStatusMessage("success", "User successfully registered.")
                appContext.setLoaded(true)
                history.push('/')
            })
            .catch(error => { 
                if (error.response.data.messages) { appContext.setErrorMessages(error.response.data.messages) }
                appContext.setLoaded(true)
            })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        return function cleanup() {
            appContext.clearAllMessages()
            // this just seems to hang, the app goes into an infinite loop at this point and freezes.
        }
    })

    return (
        <form onSubmit={registerUser}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="first_name">First Name:</label>
                <input name="first_name" type="text" className="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="last_name">Last Name:</label>
                <input name="last_name" type="text" className="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="email_address">Email Address:</label>
                <input name="email_address" type="text" className="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                <input name="password" type="password" className="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Confirm Password:</label>
                <input name="password" type="password" className="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input className="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Register" />
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: You're mentioning something about `useEffect` but you're not showing it. By the way, have you look at `error boundaries`? https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html#introducing-error-boundaries

Comment: That's because I know my way isn't working, and I don't want to bother with trying to get it to work, because it's probably ill-conceived. I want to know how other people would achieve something like a global error message component, conceptually speaking. From a high level perspective, how would experienced React developers achieve such a thing? Probably not the way I'm doing it, so let's not bother with that. I posted it more as an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: To me this looks fine. It sounds like you need a single place for all (?) your error messages to be stored so that you can render things conditionally at the root level, and using `context` will work fine. It sounds like you have an issue with repeatedly updating the global state inside the `useEffect` hook of your child component, so that's what you should be focusing on.

Comment: I added more code, specifically, the component in which I'm using `useEffect`, as far as I can tell, this should work, but it seems that everything comes to a standstill and it hangs, and creates an infinite loop.

Comment: You have infinite loop because useEffect is causing an effect itself, which triggered itself.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I don't really understand how that's happening.

Comment: Shouldn't `useEffect` essentially be like `componentWillUnmount()` in this case? I thought if you return a function inside of `useEffect`, that that is basically like using `componentWillUnmount()`

Comment: @BlaineLafreniere add an empty dependency array so that the cleanup only runs once when the component unmounts - `useEffect(() => {...}, [])`

Comment: @goto1 okay thanks I'll give that a try :)

Comment: @goto1 lol, that worked!! thank you! if you want to give an answer I'd accept it

Answer (score 0):

Use events! Send a cleanAllErrors when the user closes the event. 
In the same way listen for errors in the ErrorHandlingComponent and display errors.

If you want to make errors disapear after a timeout that is fine. For certain errors that is ok. Same here send a message. And if you want user interaction on some important error, send the message in the onClose of the error label!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting `maximum depth exceeded` is because your `useEffect` hook inside the `UserRegistration` component runs every time new `props` are received or you get new data through `hooks`.

This happens when your `cleanup` function gets triggered because it causes an update to your `context` and therefore causing an infinite re-render.

You should pass an empty dependency array so that the `useEffect` hook will behave similarly to a `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method in a `class component`:

```js
const UserRegistration = (props) => {
  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    return function cleanup() {
      appContext.clearAllMessages();
    }

    // b/c of the empty dependency array
    // this hook will only run once when
    // the component renders for the first time, and 
    // it will run the cleanup function once, 
    // when it unmounts
  }, []);
}
```